# How to sanitize "+" sign in url before searching?

Tags: javascript, search

```
// Description: I try to search Wolframalpha.com with JS search
// but I get an odd action with "+" sign, apparently because "+" is
// not just to sum things. Here an example:

var query=1+2;

// WA interpretes "+" to "%2B" after the execution
// but when I try to replace "+" with "%2B"
// WA replaces "%2B" with %225B"
// So replacing this way may end up into some odd loop
//
// How should I replace "+"/sanitize correctly?
// Or am I do it the wrong way? How to search WA in JS?

query=query.replace("+","%2B");


var url = 'http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=';
var searchUrl = url + escape(query);
window.open(searchUrl, form.target || "_blank");
```

Comment: What happens if you don't do `query.replace("+","%2B")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`escape` isn't for URL-encoding. It does something similar, but different. You want `encodeURIComponent` ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)). You also want quotes around your `query` var's value (first line below):

```
var query="1+2";

var url = 'http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=';
var searchUrl = url + encodeURIComponent(query);
window.open(searchUrl, form.target || "_blank");
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/alevu4)

`encodeURIComponent` will encode the `+` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is `var query=1+2;` it's not handling `query` as a string so `replace` is not a function that can be called on line `query=query.replace("+","%2B");`

It needs to be `var query='1+2';`

Comment: Agree ! And then there is no requirement to replace as well !